# i need my checkout page billing address should auto update once if choose the currency switcher

Tags: woocommerce

```
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'readdonly_country_select_field');
function readdonly_country_select_field( $wc_fields) {
    global $woocommerce;

  if(get_woocommerce_currency() == "INR"){
       WC()->customer->set_billing_country('IN');
       WC()->customer->set_shipping_country('IN');

       $wc_fields['billing']['billing_country']['custom_attributes'] = array( 'disabled' => 'disabled' );
      $wc_fields['shipping']['shipping_country']['custom_attributes'] = array( 'disabled' => 'disabled' );

  }
  else {
       WC()->customer->set_billing_country('');
       WC()->customer->set_shipping_country('');    
  }
    return $wc_fields;
}
```

in my above code i have used the concept if the currency is in inr then my billing country should auto update with india this is working fine but need to refresh whole page.